# using fontawesome in Firefox Webextension Contentscript

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension, font-awesome, firefox-addon-webextensions

I would like to style my Webextension with Fontawesome icons. For the Popup menu and the extension settings, this works without a problem, but my contentscripts can't access it.

To create a minimal example, I set up a repository:

```
git clone https://github.com/lhk/fa_test.git
cd fa_test
npm install -d
```

It injects the fontawesome javascript as a contentscript.
**manifest.json:**

```
"content_scripts": [
      {
        "matches": [
          "https://*.wikipedia.org/*"
        ],
        "js": [
          "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
          "./node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/js/all.js",
          "./content.js"
        ]
      }
    ],
```

And then adds an icon to the end of a website (only wikipedia though):
**content.js**:

```
$(function(){
    $('<div> <i class="fas fa-question-circle fa-2x"></i> </div>').appendTo('body')
})
```

In Chrome this works perfectly, this is how it looks:
[image]

On Firefox the icon is simply not there (please note, the scripts are only injected into Wikipedia, do your testing there).

At first I thought this was related to CSP, maybe fontawesome is making some requests to a CDN which is filtered by Firefox. But I can't find any such requests in the network pane of the developer settings.
There are also no error messages in any of the web consoles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FontAwesome is observing DOM mutations in order to replace the markup of `<i.../>` with `svg` element. From what I see, the replacement should occur within a `requestAnimationFrame` callback and for some reason the callback of `requestAnimationFrame` is not being called.
After researching and debugging I came to a very weird conclusion but I'm sure that I found the reason and even a decent workaround.

I suspect the following bug:
Within a Webextension content script, when the global `requestAnimationFrame` function is assigned to a variable without being bounded to the `window` it is not working.

Font Awesome is doing exactly this right [here](https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/blob/1cf1062e0cfda5e9b5b2cac7844721b345e1a9c5/js-packages/%40fortawesome/fontawesome-free/js/fontawesome.js#L1347), and it prevents [this callback](https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/blob/1cf1062e0cfda5e9b5b2cac7844721b345e1a9c5/js-packages/%40fortawesome/fontawesome-free/js/fontawesome.js#L1352) from being called which is cruical for the replacement process I mentioned above.

So the workaround is adding the following file to your content scripts list and it should work:

```js
/* raf-ff-fix.js */
window.requestAnimationFrame = window.requestAnimationFrame.bind(window)
```

```js
/* manifest.json */

// ...
"js": [
      "./raf-ff-fix.js",
      // ....
]
```